# Is sending a message in Objective C actually asynchronous?

Tags: objective-c

The concept of message is normally associated with asynchronous call. Is it the case for Objective C ? ie when a caller sends a message to a callee to execute a method on it, does the caller continues immediately or is it blocked until the callee finishes executing the method requested ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely blocked. Because the messages are actually translated in plain C.

```
[myObj myMethod];
```

becomes

```
objc_msgSend(myObj, @selector(myMethod));
```

at run time.

However, some methods are implemented to be asynchronous. See `-[NSTask launch]`, `-[NSThread start]`, etc.

Comment: +1, but for those asynchronous methods, the actual method is run synchronously. It's just that the work the method does is started & performed asynchronously. There's no way to make a message send asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks then my next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163489/how-to-send-message-asynchronously-in-objective-c excluding specific methods you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

No, when you read "send a message" in objective-c you must think of it as calling a method.
So, to send a message is to call a method, some are sync, some are async, you must check the docs to see that.